# Get OpenSSL custom extension added by client

Tags: c, https, openssl, handshake

I've been trying to get custom client extensions on client hello but I don`t know how to issue a method like get_custom_ext or similar.

Firstly we add the extension on the client side with SSL_CTX_set_custom_cli_ext

```
int SSL_CTX_add_client_custom_ext(SSL_CTX *ctx, unsigned int ext_type,
                                          custom_ext_add_cb add_cb,
                                          custom_ext_free_cb free_cb, void *add_arg,
                                          custom_ext_parse_cb parse_cb,
                                          void *parse_arg)
```

Now the client add one extension on every client hello, but how the server could get the custom added extension properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can register the same custom extension on the server, and use whether or not the add_cb callback is called to detect whether the client proposed the extension.

> For the ServerHello and EncryptedExtension messages every registered
>   **add_cb is called once if and only if** the requirements of the specified
>   context are met and **the corresponding extension was received in the
>   ClientHello**. That is, if no corresponding extension was received in
>   the ClientHello then add_cb will not be called.
>   (https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_CTX_add_server_custom_ext.html#EXTENSION-CALLBACKS)

I.e., do the corresponding

```
int SSL_CTX_add_server_custom_ext(SSL_CTX *ctx, unsigned int ext_type,
                                  custom_ext_add_cb add_cb,
                                  custom_ext_free_cb free_cb, void *add_arg,
                                  custom_ext_parse_cb parse_cb,
                                  void *parse_arg);
```

and let your `add_cb` call-back mark the context (or other data structure) to indicate that this connection used the custom extension.

Comment: I'm looking to implement the correct cycle to use callbacks but looks like is posible that way.